# does Git have shortcuts to refer to deeply nested files?

Tags: git

I've started using Java, and this has made my Git usage a bit more of a pain. In many Java setups the files are nested very deep, for example:

```
src/main/java/com/example/Main.java
```

So I can't use tab-complete when Git adding something, and I have to type all these directories. Is there any sort of Git setting that can help with this? For example if Git knows that there's only one Main.java that has been added, then it would be nice if `git add Main.java` just worked, but it doesn't. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Does `git add .` not work, or are you only wanting to add specific files?

Comment: you can use GUI tool like source tree

Comment: @Matt `git add .` does work, but typically I want to add individual files

Comment: Most IDEs have great support (even if third party) for this. Otherwise you can make use of source tree, tortoisegit or GitSCM GUI, as @BasilBattikhi mentioned.

Comment: It looks like `git add --interactive` can help you with this. You won't need to reference each file by its (long) name.

Comment: I rarely use `git add` with a path other than `.`. Instead I frequently use `git add -p`, which also adds the benefit of being able to add only parts of files. Try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git supports all known "Fileglobs" (see documentation for [git add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)). You may know those placeholders from regular expressions.
A list of those globs can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

In your case

```
git add src/*/Main.java
```

This may add all Main.java files in your src/ dir but is a nice "shortcut". You can even shrink it to what you already found out.

Comment: You may need to quote the glob to prevent the shell from expanding it to a different list of files than intended before `git` sees it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `git add --interactive` is what you are looking for. This is an interactive tool that allows you to stage/unstage changes. You don't have to specify the full file name because git numbers each file.

The documentation was a bit confusing for me but basically, once you enter the command you will be displayed a list of the files that have changed. You can then enter the "update" mode and select each file by their number.

To unstage files, instead of "update" you need to select the "revert" mode, then in a similar manner, you select the desired files by their numbers.

Reference - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging

Answer (score 1):

In the specific example you gave, you could say

```
git add **/Main.java
```

In this case git doesn't "know there's only one `Main.java`"; but if *you* know there's only one, this command will add it.  (If there are multiple files with that name in directories under `.`, it will add them all.)

I've always just been in the habit of starting to type each directory name, and hitting tab as I get far enough into each.  It's not as good as having a single tab complete the name; to me it's better than nothing, but I guess maybe I've just been used to it since before I knew any better :)